How to run alias command when starting a shell in a singularity container?
I need to run an alias command alias ll='ls -alF' automatically when starting a shell in a singularity container. I attempted to follow the method in the answer here by adding the alias command in customer script file /.singularity.d/env/99-zz_custom_env.sh, but it does not work. Is there any other working method to run the alias command automatically when starting a shell in a singularity container?

As I understand it you need to replace the line that is setting PS1 with the alias in the .def file proposed in the answer. Is that what you've done?

Also which shell, Bash, Sh or else? Please add the relevant tag

@kos: It doesn't work. It has nothing to do with shell type.

Please post you .def file. How does it have nothing to do with the shell type, the answer you linked is generating an rc file for Bash on the fly, so shouldn't we know which shell you want to run the alias on, so that the generated rc file is appropriate? I mean most shells (all?) define aliases using alias, but since that is not working for you knowing which shell might be helpful. What's the problem with just mentioning which shell?

@kos: Wrong. The answer I linked is not generating an rc file. If you are not familiar with Singularity, please don't mislead but let others answer. Thanks.

What happens in some random container has nothing to do with Ubuntu unless the container is also running Ubuntu.

The customer script /.singularity.d/env/99-zz_custom_env.sh is sourced by /.singularity.d/actions/shell, so the alias defined in the former is only available in these two scripts. It is not availble in normal Singularity shell.
Singularity doesn't boot, so ~/.bashrc does not take any effect. Likewise, saving alias ll='ls -alF' to /etc/bash.bashrc does not work because it is not called in normal shelling process (--norc is specified).
But if you run bash on Singularity command line manually, /etc/bash.bashrc is executed and the alias is available. But what I want is to get the alias automatically, so I need to run bash shell automatically while shelling a Singularity container. This is controlled by the SINGULARITY_SHELL variable in /.singularity.d/actions/shell script. By default, this variable is not set. So, ultimately, the solution is to set it in %environment section.
Specifically:

Add export SINGULARITY_SHELL=/bin/bash in %environment section.
Add

   echo "
alias ll='ls -alF'" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
in %post section.

To run an alias command when starting a shell in a Singularity container, you can add the alias to your .bashrc or .bash_profile within the container. Ensure the file is sourced when the shell starts by adding source ~/.bashrc to your startup script.

How do you ensure that? Show us your def file that meets the requirement in my question.
